# Mockito - How to ignore the method call of a private member object?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I want to test this method but inside the method a new object is created and then a method of that new object is called. I want to skip that (it involves logging onto a j2ee server db which I am not interested in). As a simple example, I just want to verify param1.logic() is called once, but the test ends up failing because obj tries to log on with credentials I don't want to bother entering. There are no getters or setters for the private Object2 obj variable, but is there a way to skip the constructor and following logon call?

```
public class Object1{

    private Object2 obj;

    public void method(Object3 param1, String param2){
        //functionality
        //logic to be tested
        param1.logic();
        //end functionality

        //how can I skip these two lines?
        obj = new Object2(param1);
        obj.logon(param2,param2,null, false);
    }
}
```

Here is what I attempted to use but the methods inside obj.logon are still being called.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;            

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Object2.class)
public class TestObject
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Before
    public void init() throws Exception
    {
        var1 = mock(Object3.class)
        obj2 = mock(Object2.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Object2.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(obj2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvokeStandAloneJob() throws Exception
    {        
        TestObject test = spy(new TestObject());
        Mockito.doAnswer( new Answer<Object>(){
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation){
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                return "called with arguments: " + args;
            }
        }).when(obj2).logon(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyBoolean());
        //also tried doNothing
        //Mockito.doNothing().when(obj2).logon(sDomainName, username,null, false);  

        //call method                  
        test.method(var1, var2);

        verify(var1,times(1)).logic();
    }
```

How can I make those 2 lines (the constructor and the following method do nothing?)

Comment: Look into service provider binding I'm not sure it its going to be helpful you you can bid the obj class with a mock impl for that test. Don't forget to clear runtime bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use powermock to mock the call to `new()` and return a mock object that does nothing when the logon method is called.

Before using PowerMock, make sure you follow the instructions on this page: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor

Specifically:

Make sure you add this at the top of your test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class)
```

> Use PowerMock.createMock(NewInstanceClass.class) to create a mock object of the class that should be constructed (let's call it mockObject).

Alternatively you can redesign your class to not use the `new` keyword in that method. (Its bad practice anyway)

Comment: Redesign to *not* use the `new` keyword in that method.

Comment: Is this different from PowerMockito.whenNew(Object2.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(obj2); (though this doesn't seem to work)

Comment: @user2807904 That sounds about right, didnt see that in the question. I added a few more instructions to the answer. Read the link Ive added too. Maybe you are missing PowerMock.createMock()

Comment: Bad practice, to use "new"? According to what logic? On the contrary, bad practice is to move away from actual objects and towards stateless singletons, which is the usual consequence of avoiding "new" for no good reason.

Comment: @Rogério It's bad practice in this context, as you are then tying yourself to use "Object2" implementation. If i want to swap that out for a different implementation, e.g. "Object3", I have to make code changes to this class. This creates tight coupling between the classes. One of the basic OO design principles is that you should always code to an interface and this goes against that policy. Using dependency injection is one way round this, note that nobody is suggesting to use stateless singletons.

Comment: @cowls Well, to me the example code in the question clearly looks like a proper use of `new`, because the object is *stateful*; you would *not* be able to instantiate it with the desired state by using DI. And the argument about "a different implementation" is totally bogus, since there is no indication that such a need exists here; the [coupling](http://cc2e.com/File.ashx?cid=336) is, most likely, appropriate; doing otherwise here would be unjustified over-engineering. Finally, that code *is* "coding to an interface"! Sorry to say, but you don't understand what that principle means.

Comment: @Rogério. `Object2 obj = new Object2()` is not coding to an interface.

Comment: @Rogério also, the question states that `obj.logon` involves logging on to a server db. Which is indeed a scenario where you would want to support multiple implementations.

Comment: @cowls Yes, it is. Every public class *has* a public interface. If the client code only depends on that public interface, and not on any implementation detail, then it most definitely is coded to the interface. The fact that the *implementation* of `Object2#logon(...)` accesses a db is irrelevant; the client code (class `Object1`) does not know or depend on that; it's a detail hidden behind `Object2`'s public interface.

Comment: @Rogério Yes `Object2` provides one implementation of `logon()` (agree implementation details are irrelevant). But what if you want to provide an entirely different implementation of `logon()`? You will need to change `Object1`

Comment: @cowls You can't go "what if" without having an actual *requirement* to satisfy. That can either be a business or technical requirement, but it must be a real, not an imagined one. Otherwise, what's the point? In most cases, such requirements simply are not there, so we apply the simplest design that solves the problem. Also, so what if eventually you need to change the *implementation* of `Object1`? That won't break any clients if the interface contract is obeyed, which is true whether the interface is a separate one or an implicit one.

Comment: @Rogério Obviously I don't have a requirement, it's an SO question... But yes I also agree, sometimes there is no need to optimise the design until there are certain requirements. Which is why I didn't recommend it and gave the Powermock solution to test the code as is.

Answer (score 0):

Mocks are great way to test if you rigorously follow dependency injection pattern. If you do not, mocks are not much help.

Your line below

```
obj = new Object2(param1);
```

is a violation of dependency injection.

You need to replace it with

```
obj = object2Factory.create()
```

and then inject object2Factory in constructor or as a property.

**UPDATE:**

While I still don't know how to mock the original code, I'd like to produce an alternative refactoring.

You can refactor the lines

```
    obj = new Object2(param1);
    obj.logon(param2,param2,null, false);
```

into their own package-private method:

```
Object2 createObject2(Object3 param1, String param2) {
        Object2 o = new Object2(param1);
        o.logon(param2,param2,null, false);
        return o;
}
```

You can then use `spy()` to mock createObject2().

Comment: and if I can't change the source code of the method/class I'm testing, what can be done?

Comment: Then what is the point of testing? What do you do if you find a bug?

Comment: I looked a bit more closely at your code: can't you just test `param1.logic()` directly?

Comment: The code can change when it is merged with features that other people are working on. The test is for ensuring the original functionality still works when new features are added. 
There is also logic surrounding param1.logic(), while writing the example I simplified it to focus on the problem

Comment: After refactoring with a factory, you still have the original functionality intact.

Comment: I am not allowed to refactor or touch the original code though

Comment: This answer is wrong in three ways: 1) mocks have nothing to do, inherently, with DI, since you can rather easily mock object construction (as the question itself shows); 2) instantiating directly a dependency is *not* a violation of DI, when said dependency doesn't need to be injected, since DI is meant for externally configurable dependencies which admit multiple implementations (see http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html); 3) the suggested refactorings add unnecessary complexity to the production code (over-engineering) which is not what testing is supposed to lead you into.

Comment: @Rogério Obviously, I have to disagree :) In particular, I'd like to disagree with (3). The tests are indeed nudjing us toward refactoring, but the refactoring mat be beneficial in the long run. Note that `param2` is not shown as being used anywhere except in logon() call. Could it be that `param2` is some authentication token? And if so, may be we're better off encapsulating it in factory and removing it from the `method` call? That would simplify the code and remove some coupling. Of course, this is pure speculation without the rest of the code, but it's possible.